# What's the life cycle of iOS app on an app crash?

Tags: ios, crash, lifecycle, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm trying to log a time before the app gets terminated and it seems to behave differently on an app crash so the time never gets logged.  NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler is a potential solution but I'm finding that it's not recommended if we're already using other 3rd party frameworks like crashlytics / fabric.  Can anyone suggest the proper approach to solving this problem?

Comment: The `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` only handles uncaught exceptions, which is just one way that your app can crash. Other things can crash your app, like assertion failures and invalid memory accesses.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @DietrichEpp.  Assertion failures wouldn't happen in a release app but you have a point.  I've opted not to go through this implementation for now.

Comment: It's a common choice to leave assertions enabled even in release builds. Various memory allocators will abort if they detect memory corruption.